# cakephp3: How to call functions of related models in both directions

Tags: associations, entity, cakephp-3.0

I have three Models, `A`, `B`, and `C`, where

- `A` has one `B`
- and `A` has many `C`.

If a method `A.update()` is called it also calls methods `B.task()` and `C.task()`, and thanks to contain, `B` and `C`are already available within `A`.

However what if in my `B.someTask()` method I need to call `C.anotherTask()`?

If I `debug($this)` in `A`, I see the entities `B` and `C`, but if I `debug($this)` in `B` or `C` I only see properties of that entity.

Should there not be a property in `B` (or `C`) that references entity `A` as well?

I know that I can adjust my contain and add in that `A` should contain `B,C => [A]`, but that creates a second SQL query when I should already have `A`?

Is there some trickery I am missing here?

Comment: No, there shouldn't be any references in `B` or `C` unless you explicitly contain `A`. Maybe you should rethink whatever you are doing there, cross communicating entities, that sounds really fishy. You may get better help here if you'd come up with a real world example of what you are doing there.

Comment: Well let's say I have a Car, with an Engine and Tank and a Dashboard. When the Tank is near empty it has to light up something on the Dashboard,

Comment: That's more of an analogy... what I ment with "real world example", was a concrete, non abstract example with non made up names, real data, all mashed up in a comprehensible context that illustrates what exactly you are planning to do with the data. From your "real life analogy", it sounds like this is presentational logic, which doesn't belong into entities.

Comment: I am trying to generate Notifications for a user, User has Many Notification. But these need to be generated from within logic of other entities. It sounds like I need to move things into my controller and further seperate what I have in my entities so that the return values can then be used to decide if I should generate these Notifications, even though they are a bi-product of entity logic